# React typescript Property 'map' does not exist on type 'User'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am trying to use react with typescript. I have initialized useState with an object but can't use map function with that object.

Here is the error I am getting

> Property 'map' does not exist on type 'User'

Here is the code.

Thank you in advance

```
    interface User  {
        name : string,
        email : string,
        stream_key : string,
    
    }
    
    const App = () => {
    const [liveStreams, setLiveStreams] = useState<User>({
            name : '',
            email : '',
            stream_key : ''
        })
    
    // setting livestreams
    const getStreamsInfo = (live_streams) => {
        axios.get('http://192.168.43.147:4000/streams/info', {
        }).then(res => {
            console.log(res.data)
            setLiveStreams({
                name: res.data.name,
                email: res.data.email,
                stream_key: res.data.stream_key
            })
        });
    }
    
    return (
    {liveStreams.map(data => <Text>{data.email}</Text>)}    
)
```

Comment: You only have one `User` object. Why are you trying to use `map`? And why are you using a plural for the name of the state variable?

Answer (score 2):

You only have a single `User` object, not an array of them. Either:

1. Just use the object (and ideally use the singular rather than the plural for the name of the state variable), or
2. Use an array of objects instead.

With #1, for instance, if you used the name `liveStream`, it would look like this:

```
return <Text>{liveStream.email}</Text>;
```

---

Given that you've said

> Actually res.data contains data of multiple users. How to use array of objects using typescript? Sorry for newbie questio

in a comment, it looks like you want #2, which means:

1. Make your initial data an empty array.

   ```
    const [liveStreams, setLiveStreams] = useState<User[]>([]);
    // −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^−−^^
   ```
2. When you receive the list, use the whole list:

   ```
    const getStreamsInfo = (live_streams) => {
        axios.get('http://192.168.43.147:4000/streams/info', {
        }).then(res => {
            // To *replace* state with the list in `res.data`:
            setLiveStreams(res.data);
            // >>OR<< to **add to** the current state, appending the list from `res.data`:
            setLiveStreams(streams => [...streams, ...res.data]);
        });
    }
   ```
3. Add `key` attributes to your `Text` elements, since they're entries in an array.

Comment: Actually res.data contains data of multiple users. How to use array of objects using typescript? Sorry for newbie question

Comment: @pratikjaiswal - As what, an array?

Comment: I have set up array of objects with useState. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

In your case, the actual solution will be to use a type guard to check that you have an array before attempting to use the map method.

```
if (liveStreams instanceof Array) {
    liveStreams.map(data => <Text>{data.email}</Text>);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   interface User  {
        name : string,
        email : string,
        stream_key : string,
    
    }
    
    const App = () => {
    const [liveStreams, setLiveStreams] = useState<User[]>([{
            name : '',
            email : '',
            stream_key : ''
        }])
    
    // setting livestreams
    const getStreamsInfo = (live_streams) => {
        axios.get('http://192.168.43.147:4000/streams/info', {
        }).then(res => {
            console.log(res.data)
           // is the `res.data` an Array Object?
           // or u may just do like that 
           /*
            * const { data } = res
            * // if `data` type is user[]
            * setLiveStreams(data)
           */
            setLiveStreams([{
                name: res.data.name,
                email: res.data.email,
                stream_key: res.data.stream_key
            }])
        });
    }
    
    return (
    {liveStreams.map(data => <Text>{data.email}</Text>)}    
)
```